# What is the concurrency model for Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, concurrency, event-handling, internet-explorer-11

After some research, I have to turn out to STO community for an indication (if any) on what would be the concurrency model for Internet Explorer (11, preferably). What is the equivalent for IE11 to the *EventLoop* in the Chromeverse ? Otherwise, I guess it should be interesting to get any knowledge available on the inner functioning on the event management in IE11 !

Thanks

Comment: Does it have a specific name for IE, is it the exact same mechanism ? Regarding terminology, let's not confuse "EventLoop" with "event loop".

Comment: Because I have to adress some debugging on that dead duck... So no. Well I guess I'll have to call that Microsoft employee.

Comment: fair enough, I'll remove my comments now, so as not to prejudice other readers :p

Comment: Do mean the [JavaScript Concurrency model and Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)?

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT : Yes ! However, that's for Firefox, I need that info for IE :)

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Is it a JS issue you're debugging or a native one? From the JS perspective the description on MDN is just as applicable to IE (as it's so broad). But there's lots of devil in the detail type issues.

Comment: @AndySterland: I am having some event occure in a disorderer manner, to be precise, I a do have a promise of which the then function invokes another function, something of the following form X().then((res)=>{ Y(); }, it does work as expected almost always, but it seems to fail sometimes, probably by cause of interaction with some processes, it will be an entirely another topic to explain the whole scope of the issue, moreover, it might just be a bad diagnosis. I'll take your advice and rely on Mozilla's version, that's the best available anyway.